# Passing Record Id into view and then getting back on Form Post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

MVC 3. VB.NET application.. I am trying to pass a id along to keep track of which record a file name needs to be saved in.. The problem is that the id is getting passed into the view but on post back to the controller it is being lost...I have hammered on this for hours now and I am stuck... Any Ideas??

```
 @ModelType xxxxxxxxxxx.fileUploadVM
 @Code
 ViewData("Title") = "Upload Resume"
 Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.vbhtml"
 End Code
 @Html.HiddenFor(Function(m) m.id)
<h2>Upload Resume</h2>
<p style="text-align: center">Please Upload your resume below.</p>
<ul>

<form action="UploadResume" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">   
<label for="file">Filename:</label>    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />  
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></form> 
</ul>
```

Controller functions look like this:

```
 Function UploadResume(ByVal id As Integer) As ActionResult
    Dim filevm As New fileUploadVM
    filevm.id = id
    Return View(filevm)
End Function

<AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)>
Public Function UploadResume(ByVal fvm As fileUploadVM) As ActionResult

    Dim _filename As String = String.Empty
    For Each File As String In Request.Files
        Dim hpf As HttpPostedFileBase = TryCast(Request.Files(File), HttpPostedFileBase)
        If hpf.ContentLength = 0 Then
            Continue For
        End If
        Dim savedfileName As String = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory) + "\CoursePropResumes\" + Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName)
        hpf.SaveAs(savedfileName)
        _filename = hpf.FileName
    Next

    Dim e As courseproposal = db.courseproposals.Single(Function(f) f.idCourseProposal = fvm.id)
    e.resume_file_Name = _filename
    UpdateModel(e)
    db.SaveChanges()
    Return RedirectToAction("Index")

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your @Html.HiddenFor needs to be placed inside your form.